# Why is NiceGUI displaying a notification before the function with the notification is called?

Tags: python, nicegui

When I run this code, I'm expecting the "running action" notification to not be shown until the `action` function is called, similar to how the "handling upload" notification is not shown until the `handle_upload` function is called. I'm not sure why it works as expected with `handle_upload`, but not with `action`. When I upload a file, I see both notifications, "running action" and "handling upload". When I click the "Action the Data" button, I don't see any notification. Appreciate any advice/suggestions for getting the expected behavior (and better understanding how NiceGUI works).

```
@ui.page("/submit")
def submit():
    def action_it(data: bytes) -> None:
        ui.notify("running action")

    def handle_upload(file: events.UploadEventArguments) -> None:
        ui.notify("handling upload")
        data = file.content.read()
        lines = [line for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]
        output.clear()
        with output:
            ui.label('Lines uploaded:')
            for line in lines:
                ui.label(line.decode())
    
    ui.button("Action the Data", on_click=action_it(data))
    ui.button("Cancel")

    ui.upload(on_upload=handle_upload, auto_upload=True)
    output = ui.column()
```

Comment: Are you sure in this line: `on_click=action_it(data)`? It seems like you are passing not a delegate but rather result of function execution (which in your case is None).

Comment: @markalex Ahh yes, you're right, I think that explains what's happening. Thank you for pointing that out. I will do some research on how/whether I can pass an argument to the function delegate and update my question

Comment: Just as a reference, here is a very similar discussion: https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/issues/648

Answer (score 1):

@markalex Pointed out that I wasn't passing a function delegate to `on_click` but was actually sending it the results of the function execution, and that is why I wasn't getting the behaviour I expected.

To get the behavior I wanted, I just needed to use a lambda function to call my function and pass it the argument:

`ui.button("Action the Data", on_click=lambda: action_it(data))`